# Brian Fear AKA sfdcfox - New level of fame!

Tags: discussion

For those of you who have always wonder more about the man (@sfdcfox), there is a new Salesforce Developers YouTube video:

- [Episode 5: Salesforce Stack Exchange with Brian Fear | Salesforce Developer Podcast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYmhXYvDDOc)

> This week, we are happy to have Brian Fear on the Salesforce Developer
> Podcast. Brian started his career on the platform doing customer
> support at Salesforce and is now a developer for Camping World. Brian
> loves helping people and he has quite a history of pushing some limits
> to go the extra mile and answer other people’s questions. Known by the
> alias sfdcfox, he is one of the top contributors on the Salesforce
> Stack Exchange with over 290,000 reputation points. His answers have
> helped over 7 million people and that is just amazing!
>
> We’ll hear about his personal journey as well as his insights on
> getting your questions answered on developer platforms. It’s important
> not only to ask good questions but to ask them in the right way. After
> hearing Brian’s story, you might consider contributing to the
> Salesforce Stack Exchange by answering some questions. Listen to this
> episode, and be inspired to help others!

Comment: This was awesome to hear. Brian is a beast.

Comment: Can i get an an autograph?

Comment: Looks like they are reposting episodes of the Salesforce Developer podcast to Youtube. You can find the other episodes at https://developer.salesforce.com/podcast. Presumably others will also make it to YouTube over time.

Comment: @DanielBallinger - Great! Thanks. One of my other favourite episodes: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/12/episode-8-iot-projects-with-daniel-ballinger.html

Comment: @Robs . Brian's episode was a good one. I do like that they are covering a wide range of developers and topics.

Comment: What is amazing about Brian is not just his knowledge and willingness to help, but also how polite and respectful he always is to the most dumb questions I may ask. He is a true legend.